# Footnotes in longtable p column link to the last page

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, longtable

In my MWE I have two footnotes in a longtable. The footnote in the `l` column correctly links to its text. However the footnote in the `p` column links to the end of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lp{.3\textwidth}} 
    Text\footnote{This footnote works} & Text\footnote{This footnote doesn't work}\\
\end{longtable}

\pagebreak
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Is this an error in the longtables package? The manual states that:

> **longtable** takes special precautions, so that footnotes may also be used in 'p' columns.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put `\usepackage{hyperref}` after `\usepackage{longtable}`.

`hyperref` should always be loaded last.

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{lp{.3\textwidth}} 
        Text\footnote{This footnote works} & Text\footnote{Now this footnote works too}\\
    \end{longtable}

    \pagebreak
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get all my footnotes inside the table linked to the front page of the document, not to the footnote that correctly appears in the bottom of the page. Adding `hyperref` didn't do the trick.. Any other alternative?

Comment: @user3507584 Please ask a separate question with a minimal example of the code which reproduces your problem.